# No package updates are available from the current package source for project

Tags: nuget

I ran the following in Package Manager

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

I had Package source: All and the default project was one that referenced the start up project.

The following error message appeared

```
    No package updates are available from the current package source for project 'Console4Migration'.
Update-Package : The WriteObject and WriteError methods cannot be called from outside the overrides of the BeginProcessing, ProcessRecord, and EndProcessing methods, and they can only be called 
from within the same thread. Validate that the cmdlet makes these calls correctly, or contact Microsoft Customer Support Services.At line:1 char:1
+ Update-Package -reinstall
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I changed the default project to the start up project and re-ran the command the package update was successful.

[Update]

It also turned out that I had some out of date package sources
I needed to uncheck them to stop Nuget trying to use them even if I only had nuget.org selected